# dynamically create tabs based on number of rows returned from DB in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to reactjs. Below is what im trying to achieve.
Im getting a json array back from my controller and in the UI i'm iterating over this array using map function. I have to display the result in a tabbed view. Hence im using 2 map functions - 1 to get the tab labels within li and the 2nd to get the content for each tab. While i'm able to get the 1st map with li's work, the 2nd one doesnt work. For the second one to work i need to set the class 'active' so that the content corresponding to the li clicked is displayed. Below is my code:

```
 if(this.state.testList.length > 0) {
        var tabsNode = this.state.testList.map((test, index)=>{
            return (
                <li role="presentation" className={index === 0 ? 'active' : ''} key={test.id}>
                    <a href={'#' + test.test_label} aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">{test.test_label}</a>
                </li>
            );
        });

        var tabContentNode = this.state.testList.map((test, index)=>{
            return (
                <div role="tabpanel" className={<condition_here>} id={test.test_label} key={test.id}>
                    <div className="row" key={test.id}>
                        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: test.test_location}}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        });
    }
```

Comment: I am not getting what issue you are facing?

Comment: How do you determine which tab is active? Currently it seems like tab 0 is always active. But you need to have a way of changing that. Either the tab could have an "active" property (true/false), or you need a this.state.activeTab that contains the index of active tab.